# Run a nested vscode launch.json from a git submodule

Tags: node.js, vue.js, visual-studio-code

I have two projects as submodules in my main project and each submodule has its own launch.json with environment variables. I'd like to maintain this as others on the team are working separately on these projects.

Using the following launch.json in the root will let me launch one of the submodules but without the environment variables of the nested launch.json

```
{
  "name": "Test",
  "type": "node",
  "request": "launch",
  "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}/unit-api",
  "runtimeExecutable": "npm",
  "runtimeArgs": ["run-script", "debug"],
  "port": 9229
},
```

How can i launch, merge or reference the nested launch.json without directly altering the submodule? Should i move the environment variables elsewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After intense google-fu, I found some git conversation that pointed me to use .env files. I have moved my submodule environment variables to a .env file and I load this using the "envFile" parameter in the root launch.json.

This allows me to run a custom launch configuration with submodule env vars.

[Edit] Which, btw, shouldn't be stored in a git repo any way I just remember :|